# How to check my MongoDB throughput and perfomance limit?

Tags: performance, mongodb, query-performance

How can I check how many queries per second my MongoDB is executing and whether it had reached the performance limit or not?

Comment: You can start by looking into the [serverStatus](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/) call - but you probably want to use a monitoring tool to help pick apart the actual frequency of queries contained in the ops counters. I've had good luck using [OpsDash](https://www.opsdash.com/) (no affiliation) to do basic monitoring on Mongo and get an idea of the throughput of my system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get your queries per second (and many other stats) using [`mongostat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) as well as many graphical tools (from MongoDB themselves and third parties). As for whether you have reached your maximum, that will depend on what you consider acceptable performance. If you are OK with the delay involved with fetching data from disk, then that would be vastly different than if you only find in-memory queries to be acceptable. It's basically impossible to say what your maximum is without (a lot of) context and data over time.

Comment: For people using DocumentDB, I was not able to get mongostat to work with it out of the box; maybe if I had downloaded an older version.